# c# element sort

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-4.0

I have a problem trying to sort a `Dictionary<int,Elem>`/`SortedList<int,Elem>` of elements.

I have a list of `N` elements that should appear `X` times on the list, but 
if an element is on `i` index then it cannot reappear on `i - 1` or `i + 1`. I also must respect list limits (elem N is before elem 1 and elem 1 is next to elem N).

I have two possible starting points:

1. A list of elements which have a `Times` property, which has the number of times the element should appear on the resulting list.

   Example Input:

   ```
   List<elem> elements = new List<elem>(){new Elem("star", 3), new Elem("square", 2), new Elem("circle", 3)}; 
   //Elem construct take element name, and number of times on result list
   ```
2. A list, containing all the elements I want to sort, obviously, in an unssorted fashion.

   ```
   List<elem> elements = new List<elem>(){new Elem("star"),new Elem("star"),new Elem("star"),new Elem("circle"),("circle"),("circle"),new Elem("sqare"),new Elem("sqare")};
   ```

Expected output:

```
star circle star sqare circle sqare star circle

// or any other combination in which any element is not preceded by itself
```

Better performance sort algorithms are welcome but not a must here, since this will be done infrequently.

I'm using C# 4.0 and .Net Framework 4.0.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Perhaps a few examples would illustrate what you are trying to do. Can you give some example inputs and expected outputs for those inputs?

Comment: What happens in the case where there is no such ordering? For example, `star star star circle` has no such ordering.

Comment: In that case exception should be thrown by examble: NoSortingPosibleException or something like that, but that is easy to control by having max(elem.times) * 3 < sum ( all elem.times) as prerequisite for sorting

Comment: What is the problem with using a SortedList as you suggested?

Comment: That I dont't know how to sort elements the way I want. That's why I propossed any of the 2 structures as base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a very simple backtracking algorithm (akin to the standard solution to the [eight queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle_solutions#A_standard_backtracking_solution). Let me know if you need details.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have time to test this as i do not have access to visual studio at the moment, but ill get you started.

First, id recommend taking all the objects and sorting them into three different lists.
(this is going by the fact you would be using a List, edit as nessisary,

```
List<string> circle = new List<string>();
List<string> square = new List<string>();
List<string> star = new List<string>();
foreach(string item in yourList)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case "circle":
            circle.Add(item);
            break;
        case "star":
            star.Add(item);
            break;
        case "square":
            square.Add(item);
            break;
    }
}
//then you would move to sorting them into one list, which would be
List<string> finnished = new List<string>();
int count = 0;
while(count != square.Count -1)
{
    finished.Add(square[count]);
    finished.Add(star[count]);
    finished.Add(circle[count]);
    count++
}
```

Comment: obviously this isnt an exact answer but i hope its enough to get you started!

Comment: yes, i thought something like that, but the type of elements is unknow, there could be 3, 5, 10, even 20 elements, so, that would be a problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom key class for SortedList.  e.g.

```
class MyKey : IComparer
{
    int count;
    int index; // Or maybe something else
    ...
}
```

Adding to your SortedList would involve incrementing the count variable in that values custom key if it exists.  Or adding a new key with a count of 1 if it does not.